# Obtener valor vigente en tiempo real en tabla

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, real-time

Tengo el siguiente problema, actualmente trabajo en un sistema de **tarificación** con base de datos *SQL Server*, en el cual tengo que trabajar **Precios dinámicos**.

Para lo cual tengo la siguiente tabla.

- `ID_TARIFA`: Clave Primaria Auto-incrementable.
- `ID_PRODUCTO`: Identificador del producto que se vende.
- `PRECIO`: Precio del producto.
- `FECHA_INICIO` y `FECHA_FIN` : Rango de fechas donde el precio está disponible.
- `CANTIDAD`: Indica la cantidad de productos que se puede vender a un determinado precio.
- `ACTIVO`: Me indica si el precio esta activo o no.

Coloco esta información a modo de ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que hay muchos productos y muchas tarifas y existe la necesidad de consultar esta información en tiempo real.

Teniendo en cuenta esta información, se realizó un primer set de pruebas en el que:

- Se creó un campo en la tabla que contaba la cantidad de productos vendidos al precio indicado `VENDIDOS`.
- Se creó un proceso que cada vez que se vendía un producto actualizaba el campo antes mencionado `VENDIDOS`.
- Finalmente se creó un job que se ejecutaba cada cinco minutos para actualizar los precios activos.

El resultado de estas primeras pruebas fueron que el actualizar la tabla al vender un producto y a su vez al pasar los cinco minutos con el job, terminaron bloqueando el sistema de forma que no se pudo seguir vendiendo, por lo tanto se descartó.

Luego en un segundo set de pruebas:

- Se cambió el campo `VENDIDOS` a un campo calculado que ejecutaba una función de obtención de productos vendidos.
- Se cambió el campo `ACTIVO` a un campo calculado que ejecutaba una función que en base a los parámetros devolvía si el registro estaba activo o no lo estaba.

Finalmente este segundo set de pruebas funcionó bien en un ambiente de respaldo, sin embargo al levantarlo a producción, el registro de productos vendidos y la cantidad de cálculos que se realizaban en el momento de las consultas, terminó colapsando el procesador.

La pregunta es, ¿Cuál sería la mejor forma de implementar esta validación?

Tengo la teoría de eliminar el campo `ACTIVO` y realizar siempre las consultas en caliente, con `WHERE`, `AND`, y verificar los boletos vendidos en ese momento. Sin embargo, no sé si sea el mejor acercamiento.

---

Edicion 01 / 26-10-2016

El tamaño de las tablas es el siguiente, en montos aproximados:

- Tabla de Ventas - 120.000.000 (Arox)
- Tabla de Stock- 6.000.000 (Arox)
- Tabla de Precios - 6.000.000 (Aprox)

La cantidad de conexiones activas varía entre 100 y 2000 en los periodos de mayor demanda.

Los índices de todas las tablas están optimizados, a través de pruebas análisis del plan de ejecución y SQL Server Profiler.

Para mostrar los productos se muestran listados a través de filtros que no tienen mayor complejidad ni demora, sin embargo es al consultar los “precios dinámicos” (Siempre hay uno para cada producto) en donde se produce la saturación.

Comment: Bienvenido Svalinn, la pregunta tiene mucho potencial. Sin embargo, me parece que para poder ayudarte a evaluar tus diferentes intentos necesitaríamos mas información **concreta** (cantidad de registros, volumen de transacciones, índices en las tablas, el SQL empleado, los planes de ejecución de las consultas, etc...). Sin detalles concretos que podamos evaluar y diagnosticar, entramos en el ambito de la especulación.

Comment: ¿Cuántos registros tienes? 
¿ya optimizaste tus índices?
¿Como muestras la información?¿en un DataGridView? 
¿Cuántos registros muestras en pantalla a la vez?

Comment: Acabo de realizar una actualización para aclarar un poco más los datos.

Comment: Lo que no me queda claro es cómo determinas las condiciones para obtener el precio que aplica. ¿de qué depende si está activo o no? ¿qué significado tiene la _cantidad_ de la tabla de precios?

Comment: No se te ocurrió manejar la tabla de productos precios (que sea unico), actualizable y el histórico por otro lado? Sino esa tabla cada vez va a ser más lenta de consultar. Por ejemplo tener las tablas: `ProductoPrecio`, `ProductoPrecioHistórico` y `Tarifa`. No sé qué te parece?

Comment: Hola,  @PabloClaus, actualmente así es como trabaja, la tabla histórica tiene al rededor de 100.000.000 de registros.

Comment: @jachguate las condiciones para que un precio esté activo, serian:
- La cantidad de productos vendidos, sea menor o igual a cantidad.
- El precio vigente es el que se encuentra en los rangos de Inicio y Termino.
- No se ha cumplido la fecha limite del  precio.

Comment: por qué necesitas la fecha termino y fecha límite? No puede ser una sola de esas?

Comment: No entiendo entonces para qué está la tabla de ejemplo. Cuántos productos tenés? Porque si son 1000, la tabla `ProductoPrecio` debería tener 1000.

Comment: @jachguate debido a que hay un criterio que contempla únicamente el stock de productos vendidos, es decir hasta que se agoten los precios por productos vendidos pasa al siguiente, sin considerar los rangos de fechas, pero si tiene una fecha limite que sería la que se indica.

Comment: @PabloClaus Como comenté en el tema, son precios dinamicos, un producto puede tener N cantidad de precios, dependiendo de la cantidad de demanda y/o el tiempo de vigencia del mismo precio, no es una relación uno a uno.

Comment: Svalinn, la verdad sigo sin ver la necesidad de las 2 fechas. Poniendo un ejemplo, digamos que tengo el artículo con `id_producto` 1, del que se han vendido 100 unidades (¿en toda la historia?). Estoy interesado en el `id_tarifa` 3. Agrega a mi ejemplo un par de entradas en la tabla de precios con fechas diferentes en `fecha_termino` y `fecha_limite`, que me ayuden a comprender la diferencia entre una y otra, y a entender por qué debo tener ambas.

Comment: @jachguate es un tema más de reglas de negocio, por una parte existe la  vigencia por rango de fechas y por otro el limite, son condiciones independientes pero se pueden usar las dos al mismo tiempo y cada una por separada.

Comment: Entiendo que son reglas de negocio, quiero entender cómo funcionan para plantear una solución.

Comment: has considerado particionar las tablas, esto hace que de entrada se descarten lotes de registros sin siquiera tener que evaluarlos a detalle

Comment: SignalR te va a ser utilidad, tiene soporte para que cuando actualizen desde la Base de datos, ésta mande una actualización al cliente. Revisa los siguientes enlaces:https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1029976/immediate-sql-server-record-change-notifications-w - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1188400/Beginners-Guide-to-Using-SignalR-via-ASP-NET - https://www.codeproject.com/articles/883702/real-time-notifications-using-signalr-and-sql-depe - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/874240/SignalR-Database-update-notifications-in-ASP-NET-M

Answer (score 1):

Tengo una duda respecto a la cantidad, si el total de vendidos es igual a la cantidad, entonces que sucede?, no se puede vender a ese precio, entonces a cual se vende?, supongo entonces que `Id_Tarifa` no es solo la PK si no también el orden a "utilizar" los precios.

Tener el Campo `Vendidos` y el proceso que cada vez que se vendía un producto actualizaba dicho campo, me parece la mejor opción.

La consulta SQL la considero mas optimizada que Calcular el Precio "Activo" en cada cambio o consulta, y seria algo así (en base a un articulo dado):

```
Select Top 1 Precio 
From [TabladePrecios] 
Where GETDATE() Between Fecha_Inicio and Fecha_Termino 
And GETDATE() <= Fecha_Limite
And Cantidad > Vendidos
And Id_Producto = [IdProducto]
Order By Id_Tarifa
```

Recomiendo a su vez tareas de mantenimiento, que muevan (copie y elimine) los registros que toman el rol de históricos (no se volverán a usar en la practica diaria), a fin de tener menor cantidad de registros en las tablas que se utilizan continuamente.

Paralelamente, si mi suposición del `Id_Tarifa` es correcta, y quisieras una tabla/vista con todos los precios activos al mismo tiempo, la consulta (que no puede utilizar el `Top 1` junto al `Order by`) que se me ocurre no es para nada optimizada, utilizando la clausula [Exists](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql), y seria asi:

```
Select Id_Tarifa, Id_Producto, Precio, Fecha_Inicio, Fecha_Termino, Fecha_Limite
From [TabladePrecios] TP
Where GETDATE() Between Fecha_Inicio and Fecha_Termino 
And GETDATE() <= Fecha_Limite
And Cantidad > Vendidos
And Not Exists 
    (Select *
    From [TabladePrecios]
    Where GETDATE() Between Fecha_Inicio and Fecha_Termino 
    And GETDATE() <= Fecha_Limite
    And Cantidad > Vendidos
    And Id_Producto = TP.Id_Producto
    And Id_Tarifa < TP.Id_Tarifa
    )
```

Por otro lado, la misma consulta pero utilizando por completo la subconsulta para llegar al `Id_Tarifa` utilizado actualmente, puede que sea mas lento, y seria asi:

```
Select Id_Tarifa, Id_Producto, Precio, Fecha_Inicio, Fecha_Termino, Fecha_Limite
From [TabladePrecios] TP
Where GETDATE() Between Fecha_Inicio and Fecha_Termino 
And GETDATE() <= Fecha_Limite
And Cantidad > Vendidos
And Id_Tarifa =
    (Select Min(Id_Tarifa)
    From [TabladePrecios]
    Where GETDATE() Between Fecha_Inicio and Fecha_Termino 
    And GETDATE() <= Fecha_Limite
    And Cantidad > Vendidos
    And Id_Producto = TP.Id_Producto
    )
```

Si la cantidad de consultas es considerablemente mayor a la cantidad de Updates, es considerablemente mas optimizado usar una "[Vista Persistida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986366/how-to-create-materialized-views-in-sql-server)" en base a las consultas de "Activos" posteriores en lugar de la consulta "Articulo a articulo" que plantee primeramente. Teóricamente esta tabla se reconstruirá cada vez que uno de los campos relacionados a la consulta sean modificados, pero será una tabla "física" por lo que las consultas a ésta no dependen de la tardanza en construirla, si puede demorar la primer consulta posterior a un Update de la `TablaDePrecios` hasta su reconstrucción.

Esto no quita que las tareas de mantenimiento de la tabla de precios sean una de los mayores puntos a optimizar, sin embargo, si por alguna razón no se pudiera llevar a cabo, utilizar compresión en las tablas.

De lo contrario te pido aclares el comportamiento a realizarse entre `Cantidad` y `Vendidos`.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsula las operaciones y bloquea el registro desde SQL con BEGIN TRANSACTION / COMMIT como se explica en la web de Microsoft:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql

De tal forma que cuando realices la actualización y adicción, estés seguro de que no hay nadie leyendo de un registro obsoleto. La idea general es establecer un semáforo, de tal forma que esté seguro durante la actualización de los registros que no se están realizando lecturas de un dato obsoleto.

Comment: aclaro en la medida de lo posible... aunque sin conocer la estructura y el método de acceso e inserción de datos es algo complicado hacerse una idea concreta. La idea general es establecer un semaforo, de tal forma que este seguro durante la actualización de los registros que no se estan realizando lecturas de un dato obsoleto.